Is it possible to actually eliminate the small padding-border areas on Dynamic Island? Essentially change the BG color of Dynamic Island?

The actual black curved border (at "A") is great.
But if you try to use color fill up to that border, there is padding at the edges and indeed between the four areas - pointers "B" in the image.
Is there any way to color the entire background of Dynamic Island?
I've tried everything I can think of, such as
.containerRelativeFrame(.horizontal)
.frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity) and variations
using GeometryReader, ignoresSafeArea calls, dynamicIsland#verticalPlacement etc etc.
For example, here is the code for the image above.
Is there any way to essentially set the background color of Dynamic Island ??
DynamicIsland {
    DynamicIslandExpandedRegion(.leading) {
        VStack {
            Text("Ldng")
        }
        .ignoresSafeArea()
        .background(.red)
    }
    DynamicIslandExpandedRegion(.center) {
        VStack {
            Text("center!")
        }
        .ignoresSafeArea()
        .background(.green)
    }
    DynamicIslandExpandedRegion(.trailing) {
        VStack {
            Text("Trng")
        }
        .ignoresSafeArea()
        .background(.yellow)
    }
    DynamicIslandExpandedRegion(.bottom) {
        VStack {
            Text(context.attributes.name)
            Text(context.attributes.name + "extremely long whaaa")
        }
        .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity)
        .background(Color(UIColor.TexasBackgroundBlue))
        .ignoresSafeArea()
    }


nobody knows!!!
